# Batch unsupervised classification with ERDAS 2011

Tags: erdas-imagine

I work with Erdas Imagine 2011. I would like to do an unsupervised classification and vectorization on 100 Landsat images (.tif).

- CC_2014_1.tif
- CC_2014_2.tif
- CC_2014_3.tif
- etc

However, I am new in Erdas. Please can you indicate me few materials or scripts which can help me to do the unsupervised classification and the vectorization on my images.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I consulted the link. I know how to perform the unsupervised classification and vectorization with ERDAS Imagine. Indeed, I read many materials about this. But I don't see again a document explaining batch or Builder for the unsupervised classification and vectorization while I have 100 images to handle. Thank you if you have other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical place to start would be doing some tutorials on Erdas Imagine. There are several online, including quite a few which include Supervised and Unsupervised classifications.

I.e. - University of Washington - http://sal.ocean.washington.edu/tutorials/erdas/index.html - exercise 2.

There are also a number of questions on here that may help, though it depends what exactly you are seeking to draw from the landsat imagery.